# How is the quotient space H/K is isomorphic to the orthogonal complement of K?

Tags: hilbert-spaces, inner-products, quotient-spaces, vector-space-isomorphism, unbounded-operators

I am trying to construct an isomorphic map between $H/ K$ and $K^\perp$.

Specifically, $L$ is an unbounded operator on a Hibert space $H$, with kernel $K$. How could I show $H/ K \simeq K^\perp$?

Does the quotient space $H/ K$ also have its inherent inner product? If so, does the isomorphic map preserve the inner products between $H/ K$ and $K^\perp$? ($K^\perp$ has its own inner product.)

I'd appreciate it if you'd give me any help! Thank you.

Comment: Well since $L$ is unbounded, then $K$ is not a closed subset and therefore you don’t get an inner product on $H/K$. However, $K^\perp$ is always closed.

Comment: @AlonsoDelfín Oh, thank you! Can I still have the quotient space $H/K$ and the isomorphism in this case?